# how to select only unique values from related tables

Tags: postgresql, sphinx

I have three tables:

```
 id | name
----+------
  1 | a
  2 | b
  3 | c
  4 | d

branch_1
 id | parent_id | b1_name
----+-----------+---------
  1 |         1 | aaa
  2 |         1 | bbb
  3 |         1 | ccc
  4 |         2 | ddd
  5 |         2 | eee
  6 |         2 | fff
  7 |         2 | ggg
  8 |         2 | hhh

branch_2
 id | b2_name | parent_id
----+---------+-----------
  1 | b2_aa   |         1
  2 | b2_ba   |         2
  3 | b2_bb   |         2
  4 | b2_bc   |         2
```

I want to combine these tables with only unique values. I tried this code:

```
select p.id, b1.b1_name, b2.b2_name
from parent p
left outer join lateral (select distinct b1.b1_name from branch_1 b1 where b1.parent_id=p.id order by b1.b1_name) as b1 on true
left outer join lateral (select distinct b2.b2_name from branch_2 b2 where b2.parent_id=p.id order by b2.b2_name) as b2 on true
```

but in result has duplicate values:

```
 id | b1_name | b2_name
----+---------+---------
  1 | aaa     | b2_aa
  1 | bbb     | b2_aa
  1 | ccc     | b2_aa
  2 | ddd     | b2_ba
  2 | ddd     | b2_bb
  2 | ddd     | b2_bc
  2 | eee     | b2_ba
  2 | eee     | b2_bb
  2 | eee     | b2_bc
  2 | fff     | b2_ba
  2 | fff     | b2_bb
  2 | fff     | b2_bc
  2 | ggg     | b2_ba
  2 | ggg     | b2_bb
  2 | ggg     | b2_bc
  2 | hhh     | b2_ba
  2 | hhh     | b2_bb
  2 | hhh     | b2_bc
```

I want to get:

```
 id | b1_name | b2_name
----+---------+---------
  1 | aaa     | b2_aa
  1 | bbb     | ---
  1 | ccc     | ---
  2 | ddd     | b2_ba
  2 | eee     | b2_bb
  2 | fff     | b2_bc
  2 | ggg     | ---
  2 | hhh     | ---
```

maybe it seems strange, but I need only unique values without duplicates. So how I can only unique values?

P.S. I need such a table for facet search on sphinx, so that the count of products are considered correctly, with such a request:

```
select * from facetIndex facet b1_name, b2_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function to do the outer join only on the first rows:

```
select t.id, t.b1_name, b2.b2_name
from (
  select p.id, b1.b1_name, row_number() over (partition by p.id order by b1_name) as rn
  from parent p
    join branch_1 b1 on b1.parent_id = p.id
) t
  left join (
    select parent_id, b2_name, 
           row_number() over (partition by parent_id) as rn
    from branch_2 
  ) b2 on b2.parent_id = t.id and b2.rn = t.rn
order by t.id;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/GNYF31027

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if Sphinxes Multi-Valued-Attributes could work for this. Alas they are integer only. So could put the branch tables ids into the MVA (rather than the name)

If PostgreSQL had `group_concat` could perhaps just do

```
sql_query = SEELCT p.id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b1.id) as b1, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b2.id) as b2 
FROM parent p 
    LEFT JOIN branch1 b1 ON (b1.parent = p.id) 
    LEFT JOIN branch2 b2 ON (b2.parent = p.id) 
GROUP BY p.id
```

but well dont?

... so use `sql_attr_multi` ability to run seperate queries.

```
sql_query = SELECT id, name FROM parent
sql_attr_multi = uint b1 from query; SELECT parent_id, id FROM branch1 
sql_attr_multi = uint b2 from query; SELECT parent_id, id FROM branch2
```

That does the 'joining' entirely in sphinx.

Then then can just facet on the MVA, eg SphinxQL query

```
select * from facetIndex facet b1 facet b2
```

Comment: Postgres has `string_agg()` which is the same as `group_concat()`

Comment: @barryhunter thanks for answer! O'k in postgres I can relations IDs convert to string with this code: 
`select p.id, 
    (select string_agg(t.id::text, ',') from branch_1 t where t.parent_id=p.id) as b1, 
    (select string_agg(t.id::text, ',') from branch_2 t where t.parent_id=p.id) as b1
FROM parent p 
` 
and in result 
`id |    b1     |  b1
----+-----------+-------
  1 | 1,2,3     | 1
  2 | 4,5,6,7,8 | 2,3,4
`
But b1 and b2 are a string colums. Will faceted search work correctly in this case?

Comment: Diddnt think `string_agg` supported 'DISTINCT'. Then again sphinx MVAs will naturally deduplicate (can't hold the same id multiple times in a MVA!) so not needed. As MVAs are numeric, maybe use int_array_aggregate with the ids. But yes, `sql_attr_multi = uint b1 from field;` etc would parse the ids from a string (seperated by commans)