# How to group MVA field for faceted in sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I have an index where some data's has duplicate, all fields are similar except for latitude,longitude and id (field id is not realy ID, just generated `row_number() OVER () AS id`).

it's example:

```
mysql> select id,vacancy_id,prof_area_ids,latitude,longitude from jobVacancy;
+------+------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| id   | vacancy_id | prof_area_ids | latitude | longitude |
+------+------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
|    1 |        917 | 11,199,202    | 0.973178 |  0.743566 |
|    2 |        916 | 17,283,288    | 0.973178 |  0.743566 |
|    3 |        915 | 17,288        | 0.973178 |  0.743566 |
|    4 |        914 | 30,482        | 0.973178 |  0.743566 |
|    5 |        919 | 15,243        | 0.825153 |  0.692837 |
|    6 |        919 | 15,243        | 0.825162 |  0.692828 |
|    7 |        918 | 8,154         | 0.825153 |  0.692837 |
|    8 |        918 | 8,154         | 0.825162 |  0.692828 |
|    9 |        920 | 17,283,288    | 0.958914 |  1.282161 |
|   10 |        920 | 17,283,288    | 0.958915 |  1.282215 |
|   11 |        924 | 12,208        |  0.97333 |  0.658246 |
|   12 |        924 | 12,208        | 0.973336 |  0.658237 |
|   13 |        923 | 21,365        |  0.97333 |  0.658246 |
|   14 |        923 | 21,365        | 0.973336 |  0.658237 |
|   15 |        922 | 20,359        |  0.97333 |  0.658246 |
|   16 |        922 | 20,359        | 0.973336 |  0.658237 |
|   17 |        921 | 19,346        |  0.97333 |  0.658246 |
|   18 |        921 | 19,346        | 0.973336 |  0.658237 |
|   19 |        926 | 12,17,208,292 |  0.88396 |  2.389868 |
|   20 |        925 | 12,208        |  0.88396 |  2.389868 |
+------+------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I want to group data by `vacancy_id`

```
mysql> select id,vacancy_id,prof_area_ids,latitude,longitude from jobVacancy group by vacancy_id;
+------+------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| id   | vacancy_id | prof_area_ids | latitude | longitude |
+------+------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
|    1 |        917 | 11,199,202    | 0.973178 |  0.743566 |
|    2 |        916 | 17,283,288    | 0.973178 |  0.743566 |
|    3 |        915 | 17,288        | 0.973178 |  0.743566 |
|    4 |        914 | 30,482        | 0.973178 |  0.743566 |
|    5 |        919 | 15,243        | 0.825153 |  0.692837 |
|    7 |        918 | 8,154         | 0.825153 |  0.692837 |
|    9 |        920 | 17,283,288    | 0.958914 |  1.282161 |
|   11 |        924 | 12,208        |  0.97333 |  0.658246 |
|   13 |        923 | 21,365        |  0.97333 |  0.658246 |
|   15 |        922 | 20,359        |  0.97333 |  0.658246 |
|   17 |        921 | 19,346        |  0.97333 |  0.658246 |
|   19 |        926 | 12,17,208,292 |  0.88396 |  2.389868 |
|   20 |        925 | 12,208        |  0.88396 |  2.389868 |
|   21 |        961 | 4,105         | 0.959217 |  1.280721 |
|   23 |        960 | 8,155         | 0.959217 |  1.280721 |
|   25 |        959 | 12,208        | 0.959217 |  1.280721 |
|   27 |        928 | 1,60          | 0.963734 |  1.070297 |
|   29 |        927 | 32,513        | 0.963734 |  1.070297 |
|   31 |        929 | 6,140         | 0.786553 |  0.678649 |
|   33 |        932 | 1,40,46       | 0.824627 |  0.694182 |
+------+------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Result is awesome! But problem begins when I want to get all grouped data with faceted

```
mysql> select id,vacancy_id,prof_area_ids,latitude,longitude from jobVacancy where prof_area_ids=199 group by vacancy_id facet prof_area_ids;
+------+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------+
| id   | vacancy_id | prof_area_ids   | latitude | longitude |
+------+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------+
|    1 |        917 | 11,199,202      | 0.973178 |  0.743566 |
|  191 |       1004 | 11,196,199      | 0.925335 |  2.768874 |
|  313 |       1072 | 1,11,60,197,199 | 0.963968 |  1.070624 |
|  318 |       1136 | 11,196,199      |  0.96071 |  1.448998 |
|  374 |       1097 | 11,199          | 0.785255 |  0.678504 |
+------+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------+----------+
| prof_area_ids | count(*) |
+---------------+----------+
|           202 |        1 |
|           199 |       12 |
|            11 |       12 |
|           196 |        5 |
|           197 |        3 |
|            60 |        3 |
|             1 |        3 |
+---------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Faceted result is incorrect. Because in fact data's count where prof_area_ids=199 must be 5 and not 12. So how I can group field for faceted?

## Additionaly

I fount here http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/06/21/faceted-search-with-sphinx/ but just written "If you have a MVA facet, you need to use the GROUPBY() function which returns the actual value on which the grouping was made." and without examle.

```
mysql> select id,vacancy_id,prof_area_ids,latitude,longitude,GROUPBY() as selected,COUNT(*) from jobVacancy where prof_area_ids=199 group by vacancy_id facet prof_area_ids;
+------+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
| id   | vacancy_id | prof_area_ids   | latitude | longitude | selected | count(*) |
+------+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|    1 |        917 | 11,199,202      | 0.973178 |  0.743566 |      917 |        1 |
|  191 |       1004 | 11,196,199      | 0.925335 |  2.768874 |     1004 |        2 |
|  313 |       1072 | 1,11,60,197,199 | 0.963968 |  1.070624 |     1072 |        3 |
|  318 |       1136 | 11,196,199      |  0.96071 |  1.448998 |     1136 |        3 |
|  374 |       1097 | 11,199          | 0.785255 |  0.678504 |     1097 |        3 |
+------+------------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------+----------+
| prof_area_ids | count(*) |
+---------------+----------+
|           202 |        1 |
|           199 |       12 |
|            11 |       12 |
|           196 |        5 |
|           197 |        3 |
|            60 |        3 |
|             1 |        3 |
+---------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Also faceted result is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, wanting effectively `COUNT(DISTINCT vacancy_id)` on the FACET rather than the default `COUNT(*)`, but alas it turns out

```
... FACET prof_area_ids,COUNT(DISTINCT vacancy_id) AS vacancies BY prof_area_ids
```

doesnt work. The bit before BY only supports attributes, not custom functions.

... will just have to write it out the long way, with full queries...

```
select id,vacancy_id,prof_area_ids,latitude,longitude from jobVacancy
    where prof_area_ids=199 group by vacancy_id;

SELECT GROUPBY() AS prof_area_id, COUNT(DISTINCT vacancy_id) FROM jobVacancy
    WHERE prof_area_ids=199 GROUP BY prof_area_id;
```

Same results, just slightly more verbose. ie rather than using FACET shorthand, write it
out in full, as multiple seperate queries.

Answer (score 1):

> Faceted result is incorrect. Because in fact data's count where prof_area_ids=199 must be 5 and not 12. So how I can group field for faceted?

It looks like you misunderstand how FACET works. It seems to me, that you think it takes as a base the main query's result, but it actually just does another grouping. E.g. here:

```
mysql> select g, t from idx_mva where t = 11 group by g facet t;
+------+----------+
| g    | t        |
+------+----------+
|    1 | 11,12    |
|    2 | 11,13,15 |
|    3 | 9,11     |
|    5 | 11,12,15 |
+------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+------+----------+
| t    | count(*) |
+------+----------+
|   12 |        2 |
|   11 |        6 |
|   15 |        4 |
|   13 |        1 |
|    9 |        1 |
|    3 |        1 |
+------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

for t=11 you can see that as in your case it's found 3 times in the 1st query's result, but the count for that is 6 in the FACET's query result. This is because it actually occurs 6 times in the index:

```
mysql> select * from idx_mva where t = 11;
+------+------+----------+
| id   | g    | t        |
+------+------+----------+
|    2 |    1 | 11,12    |
|    3 |    1 | 11,15    |
|    3 |    2 | 11,13,15 |
|    6 |    3 | 9,11     |
|    8 |    5 | 11,12,15 |
|   11 |    2 | 3,11,15  |
+------+------+----------+
6 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

and it happens 3 times in the 1st case only because the t's value is returned only once for each of the groups. You can use group_concat() to see more values from the same group:

```
mysql> select g, group_concat(to_string(t)) from idx_mva where t = 11 group by g facet t;
+------+----------------------------+
| g    | group_concat(to_string(t)) |
+------+----------------------------+
|    1 | 11,12,11,15                |
|    2 | 11,13,15,3,11,15           |
|    3 | 9,11                       |
|    5 | 11,12,15                   |
+------+----------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+------+----------+
| t    | count(*) |
+------+----------+
|   12 |        2 |
|   11 |        6 |
|   15 |        4 |
|   13 |        1 |
|    9 |        1 |
|    3 |        1 |
+------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to learn more about faceting here's an interactive course about that - https://play.manticoresearch.com/faceting/

Comment: I actually don't understand how facet works. I would like show faceted counts but I can't do that because result is actually wrong. Imagine this count written 12 and after click to button showing 5 data - it will be a hoax) I'm just perplexed is it really impossible to solve with sphinx?

Comment: I can't understand why you consider it wrong. Do you mean that you want to FACET only what the main query returns, not what there's actually in the index?

Comment: `Do you mean that you want to FACET only what the main query returns, not what there's actually in the index?` - most likely you are right. Because initially use `group by vacancy_id`, it would be great if FACET return count from query. But as I understand it is impossible. Maybe I will make sure that there are no duplicate data as here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105752/how-to-select-only-unique-values-from-related-tables) and then FACET to count correct for me.